# Why am I unable to slide a Div onto the screen using jquery animate?

Tags: jquery, sass, jquery-animate

I have a simple effect I am trying to achieve, but am doing something wrong.

Basically, I want to use JQuery `animate()` function to slide the form onto the screen from the right, while at the same time dialing the opacity up from 0 to 1.

I have a DIV element with a CLASS of `"contact__formContainer"`, and within that I have a very simple form with a CLASS of  `"contact__form"`.

I SASS-compiled some CSS so that `contact__formContainer` has an initial opacity set to 0 and a margin-left property set to 150vw.  In my Javascript, I have intialized a const variable `"formContainer"` and used the `animate()` function to try and decrease the value of left-margin property.

All of the examples I searched seemed to write the left-margin property as leftMargin, which has me a little confused. This is the first time I've ever used SASS, but I don't think that is the problem.

Below is the relevant HTML, SASS, and Javascript.  Thank you for taking the time to help me.  If it turns out to be something simple that I overlooked, I will take more time before I post a question... just stumped and frustrated.  Thanks again!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <title>Contact James Dyer</title>


<!--Scripting-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tingle.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.compat.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/contact_TextEffects.js"></script>
  <script src="tingle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <span class="menu-btn__burger"></span>
    </div>

    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu-nav">
        <li class="menu-nav__item">
          <a href="index.html" class="menu-nav__link">
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-nav__item">
          <a href="about.html" class="menu-nav__link">
            About Me
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-nav__item">
          <a href="projects.html" class="menu-nav__link">
            My Projects
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-nav__item active">
          <a href="contact.html" class="menu-nav__link">
            Contact Me
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="contact">
      <h2 id="title">Hi!...</h2>
        <div class="contact__formContainer">
          <form class="contact__form" action="/formHandler.php" method="post">
                
                    <label for="fname" class="fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" class="fname_input">
                 
                  
                    <label for="lname" class="lname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" class="lname_input">
                    <label for="email" class="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="email_input">
                
                
                    <label for="msg" class="message_input">Message:</label>
                    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" class="message"></textarea>
           
             
                    <button type="submit" class="button">SEND</button>
             
          </form>
      </div>

      <div class="contact__list">
        <div class="contact__email">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Email
          <div class="text-secondary">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact__phone">
          <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> Phone
          <div class="text-secondary">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact__address">
          <i class="fas fa-marker-alt"></i> Address
          <div class="text-secondary">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="social-icons">
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </div>

      <footer>&copy; Copyright 2019</footer>
    </section>
  </main>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6d2ea823d0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SASS:

```
.contact {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:url("../img/aboutPage.png") center top;
  background-size: cover;

  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:8vh;
  }
  &__formContainer {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 150vw;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    opacity: 0;
    
  }
    &__form {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 10vw);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 3vw) 9em 3vh;
      grid-template-areas: "fname fname_input lname lname_input"
                           "email email_input . ."
                           "message_input message message message"
                           ". button . .";
      align-items:start;
      row-gap: 1em;
      column-gap: 2em;
      margin-left: 15vw;
      width: 50vw;
      /* Form outline */
      padding: 1em;
      border-radius: 1em;
margin-bottom:2vh;


 /*Rest of Style attributes*/
      ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 3px solid red;
            width:auto;
            height:auto;
          }

      li {
           margin-top: 1em;
          }

      label {
            /* Uniform size & alignment */
            display: inline-block;
            width: 90px;
            text-align: right;
            margin-bottom: 1vh;
            }
.fname {
  grid-area: fname;
  width: 10vw !important;
  height: 1.5em !important;
}
.fname_input {
  grid-area: fname_input;
width: 15vw !important;
  height: 1.5em !important;
}
.lname {
grid-area: lname;
width: 10vw !important;
 height: 1em !important;
}
.lname_input {
  grid-area: lname_input;
width: 15vw !important;
  height: 1.5em !important;
}
.email {
grid-area: email;
 width: 10vw !important;
  height: 1.5em !important;
}
.email_input {
  grid-area: email_input;
width: 15vw !important;
 height: 1.5em !important;
}
.message {
grid-area: message;
width: 40vw !important;
height: 9em !important;
}
.message_input {
  grid-area: message_input;
width: 10vw !important;
 height: 1.5em !important;
}
.button {
  grid-area: button;
  width: 10vw !important;
  height: 1.5em !important;
  background:pink;
  color: orange;

  &:hover {
     background:#ebb476;
     color: red;

  }

}

        input,
        textarea {
           /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
             By default, textareas have a monospace font */
                font: 1em sans-serif;

             /* Uniform text field size */
                 width: 25vw;
                 box-sizing: border-box;

             /* Match form field borders */
               border: 1px solid #999;
              grid-area: message;
          }

          input:focus,
          textarea:focus {
           /* Additional highlight for focused elements */
                border: 2px solid pink;
                padding: 0.5em;
                
          }

          textarea {
             /* Align multiline text fields with their labels */
               vertical-align: top;

             /* Provide space to type some text */
              height: 5em;
              grid-area: message;
          }

      
       

    }

  
  &__list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left:2em;
  }

&__phone {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

  .social-icons {
    position: initial;
  }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const contactMe = $("#title");
    const formContainer = $(".contact__formContainer");
    console.log("The contact page script is recognized");
    contactMe.textillate({
        in: { effect: 'fadeInUp' },
        loop: true,
        out: { effect: 'fadeOutUpBig' },
        delayScale: 1,
        delay: 150,
        });

    
 formContainer.animate({
    opacity: 1,
    marginLeft: "-=50vw",
    
 }, 5000, function() {
    //Animation complete
    formContainer.css("margin-left","5vw");
    formContainer.css("opacity","1");
  } );




});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should take more time reading the reference material.  I changed the position attribute to "relative" and it works now.

Comment: The position attribute of what?